# When did Jaime reveal to Tyrion the real reason he killed his King (Mad King)?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the S06E09 of *Game of Thrones*, "Battle of the Bastards", Tyrion argues with Daenerys that burning cities to the ground is not a good choice in war. He reveals to her the real reason Jaime, the Kingsguard, killed his King, the Mad King.

I am pretty sure that Brienne is the only person to whom Jaime reveals this truth, both in the books and in the show onscreen. I don't think Jaime ever revealed it to Tyrion on-screen in the show (I might be wrong, please point to the scene if I am). Do the books have a conversation between them regarding this, or is it also implied off-paper (for a lack of a better term).

Comment: I tried to find the discussion between Jamie and Tyrion when Tyrion is in prison in King's landing, but that book has been lent to a friend.  For some reason I believe that is when the revelation took place.  Will confirm and answer when I have the book again.

Comment: Most likely off-screen. It's ok that sometimes people talk about things which we've not heard. I for one think that it takes away from Jamie and Brienne's relationship, being that she's the only person Jamie has ever told. However, if he has at some point confided in Tyrion, then it shows that they had some sort of relationship.

Comment: sorry, what makes you think this is a big secret? my impression was that a lot of the higher-ups know what went down. brienne didn't know until jaime told her b/c she's generally out of the loop of royal goings on (i.e., not a higher-up).

Comment: @dbliss Jamie specifically tells Brienne that she's the only person in the world he has confided in.

Answer (score 6):

The Answer is simple, Jaime never told Tyrion anything about it on-screen so given that Tyrion does know about it, We can assume that directors implied that Jaime told Tyrion off-screen. It did not happen in any episode.

People that Jaime has told about Aerys and his last orders are are:

1. Brienne of Tarth (He told her the whole story in bathtubs of Harrenhal)
2. Tywin Lannister (He gave him half truth. He told him only about the execution orders Jaime received from Aerys for Tywin.)

Personally I am more of the idea that it was just a brain-fart from the *creative* writers who gave us the gem called "Bad p***y" and the ridiculous Dorne plot. We are now just building legs for them to stand on

Comment: Jaime telling Robert/Selmy hints >absolutely nothing< about Wildfire Caches. Aerys liked burning people. He burned people alive as a means of execution all the time near the end, and one of them was Brandon Stark. That's enough association with Aerys and burning people to change a conversation from a jokey mood (what Robert was going for) to a serious mood (what Jaime shut him up with).

Comment: @DariM I stand corrected. Funny I had forgotten Aerys' reputation as a pyromaniac which was so huge that Red priests send Thoros from Essos to convert him.

Answer (score 3):

In Season 4, Episode 6, 'The Laws of Gods and Men', Jaime says to Tywin:

> "Do you know the last order the Mad King gave me? To bring him your head. I saved your life so you could kill my brother?"

I'm not sure if this is what you meant by reasons discussed later by other characters, as I am only up to that scene. So Brienne isn't the only one Jaimie has told, he has also at least told Tywin.

Comment: +1 He also tells Robert in the first season that Aerys's last words were "Burn them all", in the war stories scene. It's clear that in the TV show he has told little pieces of the story to many people. He does say to Brienne in season 3 that she's the only person he's told the *whole* story to, though - so he either told Tyrion the whole story later, or, Tyrion pieced the pieces together himself and filled in the gaps using what he'd learned about wildfire.

Comment: @user568458  "the whole story," whatever that means. i think that was more something he said to establish intimacy w/ brienne than it was a literal truth for obsessive viewers to use to infer who knows what.

Answer (score 2):

There is no scene where this happens in the show (or the books, for that matter). The implication is that it happened off-screen at some unknown earlier time, but mostly it's just a plot device to tease the threads of the (presumed) wildfire rumours together across episodes.

Note that for the Battle of the Blackwater, the show avoids any mention of wildfire caches as well. Whereas the book combines the two - the alchemists are creating wildfire as well as finding caches left behind from the Mad King's reign, the show only has the mass production going on.

> "No, no," Hallyne squeaked, "the sums are accurate, I swear. We have
>   been, hmmm, most fortunate, my lord Hand. Another cache of Lord
>   Rossart's was found, more than three hundred jars. Under the
>   Dragonpit. ...."

-Tyrion, ACoK

Answer (score 0):

They are siblings, and spoke with and confided with each other their entire lives. Having already shown that conversation with Brienne, I don't think they felt the need to re-do it with a different listener, so probably implied/off-screen.